# iTextSharp Fill pdf form with Hebrew text show nothing

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, hebrew

I have a pdf file with form that need to fill using iTextSharp library.
it's working while i insert numbers or text in english but show nothing when choose hebrew,
here is my code

```
        string basePath = @"C:\c_project\pdfTest\";
        using (FileStream outFile = new FileStream(basePath + "result_bold.pdf", FileMode.Create))
        {
            // Path to font
            string ARIALUNI_TFF = Path.Combine(basePath, "FbHadasaNewBook-Bold.otf");

            //Create a base font object making sure to specify IDENTITY-H
            BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(ARIALUNI_TFF, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);

            // Pdf with form
            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(basePath + "form.pdf");
            PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, outFile);

            AcroFields fields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;

            fields.SetField("date", "TEST"); // Working
            fields.SetField("t.z", "בדיקה"); // Show nothing in new pdf

            fields.AddSubstitutionFont(bf); // Set font style to all fields

            pdfStamper.Close();
            pdfReader.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I rearrange the code like this, move AddSubstitutionFont() befor the SetField and now it's working

```
fields.AddSubstitutionFont(bf);

fields.SetField("date", "TEST");
fields.SetField("t.z", "בדיקה");
```

Now i get the hebrew text.